# what is Open XMl file for office 2007?

Tags: outlook

What is the open xml file for office 2007. In fact I want to know open xml file for the outlook so that I can add new contact in outlook. please guide me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you can tell by reading the [ECMA-376 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm), the OpenXML format is only used to store diagram drawings, spreadsheets, presentations and word processing documents. It has nothing to do with outlook contacts.

Comment: ok thanks. Is this means we cannot add the new contact through xml open file ?

Comment: @Lalit: yes, that is what it means.